# How do I allow breaking on 'System.NullReferenceException' in VS2010?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2010, nullreferenceexception, break

I have a VS 2010 C# .NET 4 project. The issue is that the program is not breaking on 'NullReferenceException' errors during debugging.

The output window will display the following:

`A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in myProgram.exe`

...but the debugger will just exit out of the function and continue running the rest of the program.

How do I change this behavior so that the debugger will break on these exceptions?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Go to Debug -> Exceptions -> Search for `NullReferenceException` and check the "thrown" checkbox.

Comment: Thanks. Never would have found that.

Comment: heh, such typos sneak in from time to time.

Comment: Wow.. 3 years I have been wondering how to do that. I should really use more button in VS than build and run.

Comment: Shortcut is CTRL +  ALT + E

Comment: It is now hidden in Debug > Windows > Exception Settings.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2012: DEBUG > Exceptions... then click Find...